# Sorting objects by their classes

Tags: python, oop

I have to model objects which have an arbitrary set of labels. I'm considering to model the labels as objects instead of just strings because I want them to have their own behavior.

For example, the tags could be:

```
class Jurisdiction():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    #(...)

class EconomicSector():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    #(...)
```

and a variable (object) could be the private spending on agriculture. I would represent it as

```
obj_1 = { EconomicSector("Agriculture"), Jurisdiction("Private")}
# It should be of its own class, but a set of labels will do for now
```

The labels could have different orderings so I want to define one by convention. Say, the Jurisdiction goes before the EconomicSector:

```
order = [Jurisdiction, EconomicSector]
```

Therefore, when I want the object represented as string I would get "Private.Agriculture" instead of "Agriculture.Private".

The problem is that to know the precedence of a label I have to ask for its class and compare between classes. This goes against OOP principles because an object should be self-contained and defined by the messages it responds to. I shouldn't have to deal with their classes.

An example of getting the string representation by comparing classes:

```
obj_1_with_precedence = [(order.index(label.__class__),label) for label in obj_1]
obj_1_sorted = [label_tuple[1] for label_tuple in sorted(obj_1_with_precedence)]
obj_1_with_strings = [label._name for label in obj_1_sorted]
obj_1_as_string = ".".join(obj_1_with_strings)
print(obj_1_as_string) # 'Private.Agriculture'
```

Is there a better way to model this problem or should I just compromise with comparing between the classes of objects?

Comment: Form a list of tuples `[(Jurisdiction, EconomicSector), (etc), etc]` and then define a key function that sorts that list based on that tuple as you desire. Untuple the resulting list. Maintains OOP and sorts as defined...

Comment: @dawg, so the ordering would be explicit on the variables? The variables shouldn't have to have the responsibility of ordering their labels. The order should be imposed by another object.

Comment: You would need to override the comparison magic methods of each class. More [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Comment: You would use the order of `order` that in your key function. Or you can introduce a third object type for ordering.

Comment: If you add more explicit input, output examples, I can cobble together an example...

Comment: @EcirHana, it would still be metaprogramming. I would have to override the behavior of classes, when I should be only defining the behavior of their instances

Comment: How about an ordered enum?

Comment: @dawg, I added an example when using the classes of the labels

Comment: class SpendingReport has-a EconomicSector, has-a Juristiction? def __lt__, def __repr__ (or str). Or is the problem that you don't know which kinds of tag-objects are going to be in your collection?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do.  Give each class an attribute which defines the order they should be sorted in, and define the rich comparison methods to look at that attribute.  For example:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Base:
    _sort_order = None
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._sort_order < other._sort_order

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._sort_order == other._sort_order


class Jurisdiction(Base):
    _sort_order = 1

    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    #(...)


class EconomicSector(Base):
    _sort_order = 2

    def __init__(self,name):
        self._name = name
    #(...)
```

(You'll get an error if you try to compare an instance of Base and an instance of one of its subclasses.  Base is not supposed to be instantiated.)  If you define the classes in the order they should be sorted in, you can define a function to automatically give you the next number, so you don't have to keep track of it manually, for example:

```
_id = 0
def _next_sort_id():
    global _id
    _id += 1
    return _id

# definition of Base class

class Jurisdiction(Base):
    _sort_order = _next_sort_id()
    #(...)

class EconomicSector(Base):
    _sort_order = _next_sort_id()
    #(...)
```

If you want to get even fancier you could define a metaclass that would automatically assign the next sort id when you define a new subclass, and then you would just need to be sure your classes are defined in the right order and have the right base class.